# querying for rows in a table and exempting specific rows if they exist in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two different tables with a similar column in both. And i need to query for all rows in table A but must exempt specific rows in table A if those rows exist in table B.

Example:

```
Table A
---------------------------------
item_id  |  item_name |  price
---------------------------------
  1      |   apple    |   100
---------------------------------
  2      |   banana   |   150
---------------------------------
  3      |   ginger   |   120
---------------------------------
  4      |   pear     |   150
---------------------------------
  5      |   berry    |   120
---------------------------------


Table B
---------------------------------
item_id  |  item_owner | 
---------------------------------
  1      |   Ben       |  
---------------------------------
  2      |   Damian    |  
---------------------------------
  3      |   Greg      |   
---------------------------------
```

Based on the example above, I need to run a query to fetch all the rows in table A if item_id does not exist in table B.

The result of this query should fetch only 2 rows which are:

```
---------------------------------
  4      |   pear     |   150
---------------------------------
  5      |   berry    |   120
---------------------------------
```

Would ber glad to get help with this...Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE item_id NOT IN(SELECT item_id  FROM tableb);
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20f8a/1).

Answer (score 1):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.item_id = b.item_id
WHERE b.item_id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc58/1)

For faster performance, you must define an `INDEX` on column `item_id` on both tables to prevent server to perform `FULL TABLE SCAN`.

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
A.*
from
A LEFT JOIN B on (A.item_id=B.item_id)
where B.item_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
SELECT A.*
FROM   TableA A FULL OUTER JOIN TableB
       ON A.Item_id = B.Item_ID
WHERE  B.Item_ID IS NULL
```